# Isolating a dangerouslySetInnerHTML div from global CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js

I'm seeing discrepancies in styling when I render an email HTML string (which has all its styles defined in-line) in my NextJS React app, like so:

```
<div id='emailContent' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: sanitizedHtml }} />
```

My assumption is that my global CSS styles are clashing with the inline styles in the HTML string. What supports this guess is that the styles look perfect when I render using an `iframe` (which I know isolate its contents from global CSS by default) like so:

```
<iframe srcDoc={sanitizedHtml} />
```

Unfortunately, with my use case, I can't go with this solution because it takes much longer to render the HTML than using the `dangerousSetInnerHTML` method.

**Is there any way to ensure this div *only* renders with the CSS styles defined in-line the HTML, and ignore any CSS styles set globally?**

**What I've tried:**

Setting this CSS globally:

```
#emailContent { 
  all: revert; /* also tried unset */
}

#emailContent * { 
  all: revert; /* also tried unset */
}
```

... which is giving me mixed results - various combos of `revert` and `unset` fixes the styling for some of the emails, but not others.

Wondering if there is a more straightforward solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `iframe` solution was slow to load due to a separate issue. With that fixed, this seems to be the way to go!